# Remark about stem field containing two roots

Tags: galois-theory

In Intro to Galois Theory on coursera the lecturer gives the definition "Let $P \in K[x]$ irreducible, monic polynomial. A stem field for P is an extension $E$ of $K$ such that $\alpha \in E$ is a root of $P$ and $E = K[\alpha]$."

After proving any two stem fields are isomorphic, the lecturer remarks "In particular, if a stem field contains two roots of $P$, there is an automorphism which takes one to the other."

$\text{Question}$: How can a stem field contain two roots? Based on the definition the only way a stem field can contain two roots is if $\alpha$ is a root of degree $2$, in which case the remark doesn't achieve anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of examples where $K(\alpha)$ contains more than one root of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. For example, if $\zeta_n$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity (meaning $\zeta_n^n = 1$, and $\zeta_n^d \neq 1$ for all $0 \leq d < n$), then the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_n$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is the $n$-th [cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) $\Phi_n$, and all of the other roots of $\Phi_n$ are also primitive $n$-th roots of unity and therefore are integer powers of $\zeta_n$. (In this case, $\zeta_n \mapsto \zeta_n^a$ induces an automorphism of the cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ for each integer $a$ with $\gcd(a, n) = 1$.)

Much more generally, if $E/K$ is any Galois extension of fields, then $E = K[\alpha]$ for some $\alpha \in E$ by the [primitive element theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem), and if $P \in K[x]$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, then $K[\alpha]$ contains *all* roots of $P$. If you want specific examples, you can find plenty in the [LMFDB's database of number fields](https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/).

(By the way, I've never heard the term "stem field" before—I don't think that's standard terminology.)